# Jquery - How can I dynamically add a clickable element after redraw

Tags: jquery

I have seen other posts on this topic but they always change elements on redraw. I have a list of items, I want to click on one and delete it via ajax and then redraw the same list and have it clickable. The click after redraw isn't working. The following code redraws the list fine, once. Then the 'listto' items are no longer clickable. I thought 'on' was supposed to handle this. How can I make this work?

```
$('.listto').on('click',function() {
    var tmp = $(this).attr('id').substr(1).split("|");
    $.ajax({url: '/contact/removefromlist/'+tmp[0]+'/'+tmp[1],
        success: function(data) {
            redrawtolist(data,tmp[1])
        }
    });
});

function redrawtolist(data,item) {
    var dat = JSON.parse(data);
    var str = "";
    $.each(dat, function(index, rel) {
        str += '<div id="t'+index+'|'+item+'" class="listto">'+rel+'</div>';
    });
    $('#tolist').html(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your handler to that :

```
$('#tolist').on('click', '.listto', function(){})
```

Using event delegation is the good way to bind event to dynamicly added elements.

You have plenty information about direct binding and delegated binding on this page : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I knew I was close... This makes sense. Thanks! And it works.

Answer (score 2):

When you replace the elements, the handlers are gone.  You can use event delegation to fix this:

```
$('#tolist').on('click', '.listto', function() {
```

Now as long as `#tolist` is not replaced, the handler will not be removed by replacing `.listto` elements.

You can read more about event delegation in the [`on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're attaching an event to an element that isn't ready to receive that event. You should attach the event to a parent element, then you can filter for the `.listto`. This way it doesn't matter when your click able elements get added, it will work. This is called event delegation. You're delegating the task of handling the event to another element.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <button>Click here to add book.</button>
</body>
```

And your JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".listto", function() {
    alert('it works!');
});
```

Also when doing this, don't attach it to a parent that's too high up the tree. You want to attach it to the nearest possible parent element. We don't need to have a click event on something like `document` because it's a good idea to be specific of which elements will get this event. Attaching it to `document` will mean that any element, that has the class of `.listto`, will be click able and respond to the same code. If you want to have different functionality in different buttons, you can't, because they're all responding to the same code attached to `document`.

```
$('#tolist').on("click", ".listto", function() { //This would be best, but will only work if #tolist is not dynamic
    alert('it works!');
});
```